# How to configure Laravel Mix to access a site in my local network?

Tags: laravel, networking, laravel-mix, laravel-valet

I have a Laravel/React project that I'm running with Valet in my main computer at `https://mysite.test` and I followed the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet#sharing-sites-on-your-local-network) to share it in my local network.

On the same network, I can access it at `https://192.168.0.10/mysite.test,` and it loads the HTML, but I get a 404 error for all the assets.

It seems the issue is that it's trying to load the files like `https://192.168.0.10/js/app.js` instead of `https://192.168.0.10/mysite.test/js/app.js`.

This is how **webpack.mix.js** looks like:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .react()
  .options({ processCssUrls: false });

const host = 'mysite.test';
const homedir = require('os').homedir();

mix.browserSync({
  proxy: `https://${host}`,
  host,
  port: 8000,
  open: 'external',
  https: {
    key: `${homedir}/.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.key`,
    cert: `${homedir}/.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.crt`
  }
});
```

Comment: What value do you have in your .env file for APP_URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `publicPath()` to 'public/mysite.test' and adjust the output paths of your assets accordingly.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('public/mysite.test')
   .js('resources/js/app.js', 'js').react()
   .options({ processCssUrls: false });

const host = 'mysite.test';
const homedir = require('os').homedir();

mix.browserSync({
  proxy: `https://${host}`,
  host,
  port: 8000,
  open: 'external',
  https: {
    key: `${homedir}/.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.key`,
    cert: `${homedir}/.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.crt`
  }
});
```